# React-Native App works perfectly on expo, but after publishing it shows unseen behaviour

Tags: react-native, expo

A React-Native Calculator with expo-cli after publishing on expo, it shows unseen behaviour with  multiplication and division operation.
I stuck at this for weeks so, please help.

Github Link: https://github.com/A-phenomenal1/Calculator-app.git

Every suggestion is welcome, please reply.

Comment: Please add some code example and to not link on another website or whole repository on GitHub.

Comment: but its working is as expected on expo client server, the problem is with published app. so i don't know which part of code does this. that's why i uploaded the GitHub link. 
so please see the problem by publish that app, please